# AS3 random movieclip from array without repeat (including timer)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, random, timer

I'm at a loss as to how I can draw one movieclip at a time from an array after like 10-20 seconds. There are five different movieclips, so not one movieclip is the same. The timer needs to reset when the drawn movieclip is removed, and then it needs to pull another movieclip from the array after 10-20 seconds. A drawn movieclip may not be used again, so it should be removed from the array, when it is removed from the stage. These script are in separate .as files.

This piece of code has the timer already (credits to [Kevin McGowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940874/kevin-mcgowan))

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

// Your Sprite / MovieClip
var clip:MovieClip;
// The time until you want to add the first one
var timeToAdd:uint = Math.random() * 20;
// This will be the timer
var _timer:uint;

// This will add us to the stage after the random time. Second variable is seconds, so we need to multiply by 1000.
_timer = setTimeout(addToStage, timeToAdd * 1000);

// Called when the timer expires
function addToStage():void{
    clip = new MovieClip();
    // You would need logic to decide when to remove it, but once it is removed this will fire
    clip.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemove);
}

// Called once removed
function onRemove(e:Event):void{
    // Remove the event listener
    clip.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemove);
    // Restart the timer
    timeToAdd = Math.random() * 20;
    _timer = setTimeout(addToStage, timeToAdd * 1000);
}
```

I hope you guys can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to start by creating an Array of Mcs...

```
//Add 5 MCs to array
var mcArr:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 0; i<5; i++) {
    mcArr.push(new MovieClip());
}
```

You can use Array.pop() to remove the last element from the array and return the value of that element.
If you want the first element from the Array, use Array.shift().
Change your addToStage function to this:

```
function addToStage():void
{
    clip = mcArr.pop();
    //clip will be null after the fifth MC. Check that clip is not null before trying to add listener
    if(clip)
        clip.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemove);
}
```